# ImportError: No module named objects in facebook ads api

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to use Facebook Ads API, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named objects
```

This is my code:

```
from facebookads.objects import (
    AdUser,
    Campaign,
)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use

```
pip install facebookads==2.5.0
```

The objects was deprecated from `2.6.0`. You can see header in the objects file

```
"""
DEPRECATED

This file is kept for backward compatibility.
Please use objects in adobjects folder instead.
"""
```

Comment: Where did you find these comments?

Comment: In my virtual environment `/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/so1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/facebookads/objects.py`. This file has that message at top from `2.6.0`